# weak_ptr to singleton not thread-safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, weak-ptr

I'm writing a function that returns a shared_ptr to a singleton. I want the singleton object to be destroyed when all of the references have gone away. My solution builds on [this accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14455) which uses a static `weak_ptr` and `mutex`, but my test for its thread-safety does not pass consistently.

Here is a complete example that illustrates the problem.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// Number of instances of this class are tracked in a static counter.
// Used to verify the get_singleton logic (below) is correct.
class CountedObject {
private:
    static atomic<int> instance_counter;

public:
    CountedObject() {
        int prev_counter = instance_counter.fetch_add(1);
        if (prev_counter != 0)
            // Somehow, 2 objects exist at the same time. Why?
            throw runtime_error("Constructed " + to_string(prev_counter + 1) +
                                " counted objects");
    }
    ~CountedObject() {
        instance_counter.fetch_sub(1);
    }
    static int count() {
        return instance_counter.load();
    }
};

atomic<int> CountedObject::instance_counter{0};

// Returns reference to a singleton that gets destroyed when all references
// are destroyed.
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> get_singleton() {
    static mutex mtx;
    static weak_ptr<T> weak;
    scoped_lock lk(mtx);
    shared_ptr<T> shared = weak.lock();
    if (!shared) {
        shared.reset(new T, [](T* ptr){ 
            scoped_lock lk(mtx);
            delete ptr;
        });
        weak = shared;
    }
    return shared;
}

// This test passes consistently.
TEST(GetSingletonTest, SingleThreaded) {
    ASSERT_EQ(CountedObject::count(), 0);

    auto ref1 = get_singleton<CountedObject>();
    auto ref2 = get_singleton<CountedObject>();
    ASSERT_EQ(CountedObject::count(), 1);

    ref1.reset();
    ASSERT_EQ(CountedObject::count(), 1);
    ref2.reset();
    ASSERT_EQ(CountedObject::count(), 0);
}

// This test does NOT pass consistently.
TEST(GetSingletonTest, MultiThreaded) {
    const int THREAD_COUNT = 2;
    const int ITERS = 1000;
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back([ITERS]{
            // Repeatedly obtain and release references to the singleton.
            // The invariant must hold that at most one instance ever exists
            // at a time.
            for (int j = 0; j < ITERS; ++j) {
                auto local_ref = get_singleton<CountedObject>();
                local_ref.reset();
            }
        });
    for (auto& t : threads)
        t.join();
}
```

On my system (ARM64 Linux, g++ 7.5.0), the multi-threaded test usually fails:

```
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from GetSingletonTest
[ RUN      ] GetSingletonTest.SingleThreaded
[       OK ] GetSingletonTest.SingleThreaded (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GetSingletonTest.MultiThreaded
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Constructed 2 counted objects
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've omitted `cout` messages from the code for brevity, but separately I've added messages to debug what's happening:

```
[thread id,  message]
...
547921465808 Acquired lock
547921465808 Weak ptr expired, constructing
547921465808 Releasing lock
547929858512 Acquired lock
547929858512 Weak ptr expired, constructing
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Constructed 2 counted objects
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It appears that thread 1 determines the singleton has expired and re-constructs it. Then thread 2 wakes up and *also* determines the singleton has expired, even though thread 1 has just re-populated it - as if thread 2 was working with an "out-of-date" version of the weak pointer.

How can I make the assignment to `weak` from thread 1 immediately visible to thread 2? Can this be achieved with C++20's `atomic<weak_ptr<T>>`? My project is restricted to C++17, so unfortunately that is not an option for me.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: That second call to `scoped_lock lk(mtx);` occurs in a lambda for the custom deleter - not within the execution of `get_singleton()` itself. Also, the output clearly indicates the runtime error was thrown in the `CountedObject` constructor.

Comment: Sorry, got it. I did not notice it on my phone screen.

Comment: It looks strange. If the compiler reads and keeps a reference to a control block of the shared pointer before the mutex lock, I would say it's a compiler bug. Could you show the assembler of `get_singleton`? Will `static volatile weak_ptr<T> weak;` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment under lock will be visible to any other thread checking the `weak_ptr` under lock.

The reason multiple instances exist is that the destructor order of operations doesn't guarantee otherwise. `!weak.lock()` isn't equivalent to "with certainty, there are no instances of this object". It is equivalent to the inverse of "with certainty, there is an instance of this object". There may be an instance, because the reference count is decremented before the deleter has a chance to act.

Imagine this sequence:

- Thread 1: `~shared_ptr` is called.
- Thread 1: The strong reference count is decremented.
- Thread 1: It compares equal to zero, and the deleter begins.
- Thread 2: `get_singleton` is called.
- Thread 2: The lock is acquired.
- Thread 2: `!weak.lock()` is satisfied, so we construct a new instance.
- Thread 1: ... meanwhile, we are waiting to acquire the lock ...
- Thread 2: The new instance is constructed, and assigned, and the lock is released.
- Thread 1: Now, the deleter can acquire the lock, and delete the original instance.

EDIT:

To accomplish this, you need some indicator that there is no instance. That must be reset only after the instance is destroyed. And second, you need to decide what to do if you encounter this case where an instance exists but is being destroyed:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> get_singleton() {
    static mutex mtx;
    static weak_ptr<T> weak;
    static bool instance;

    while (true) {
        scoped_lock lk(mtx);

        shared_ptr<T> shared = weak.lock();
        if (shared)
            return shared;

        if (instance)
            // allow deleters to make progress and try again
            continue;

        instance = true;
        shared.reset(new T, [](T* ptr){ 
            scoped_lock lk(mtx);
            delete ptr;
            instance = false;
        });
        weak = shared;
        return shared;
    }
}
```

To put it a different way, there are these states in the state machine:

1. no T exists
2. T is being constructed, but can't yet be accessed
3. T exists and is accessible
4. T is being destroyed, and can no longer be accessed

The bool lets us know that we are in state #4. One approach is to loop until we are no longer in state #4. We drop the lock so that deleters can make progress. When we retake the lock, another thread may have swooped in and created the instance, so we need to start at the top and re-check everything.

Comment: Interesting. I mistakenly assumed that decrementing the reference count to 0 and performing the destructor took place as some kind of atomic transaction. Your sequence of events makes sense. However, this begs the question if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible? Can I change my code to have the desired behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks to Jeff for his explanation and answer. I'm accepting his answer, but I want to post an alternative implementation, which in my (admittedly limited) tests, performed slightly better. Your mileage may vary.

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> get_singleton() {
    static mutex mtx;
    static weak_ptr<T> weak;
    static atomic<bool> deleted{true};
    scoped_lock lk(mtx);
    shared_ptr<T> shared = weak.lock();
    if (!shared) {
        // The refcount is 0, but is the object actually deleted yet?
        // Spin until it is.
        bool expected;
        do {
            expected = true;
        } while (!deleted.compare_exchange_weak(expected, false));

        // The previous object is definitely deleted. Ready to make a new one.
        shared.reset(new T, [](T* ptr){ 
            delete ptr;
            deleted.store(true);
        });
        weak = shared;
    }
    return shared;
}
```

This removes the lock acquisition from the deleter and replaces it with an atomic flag that becomes true when the object actually gets deleted.